# No prompt after changing console parameter

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, embedded-linux, u-boot

In order to test whether one of UART port is working or not in i.MX6 SoC, Modified the console argument from ttymxc0 to ttymxc1 in u-boot.

I was able to get the boot log printed on the screen as well as whatever I type from my keyboard was displayed on the serial console. Only one thing was not working is that it was not displaying console prompt so that I can run commands ( e.g. ps ) whereas it works when the console is set to ttymxc0. What commands to run for the console prompt to be available with ttymxc1

Note: I am using an customized i.MX6 Board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To login in via a serial console you need a getty process serving it. If you are using systemd the responsible service is serial-getty@.service. Please, read

- man 8 getty
- man 5 securetty
- man 8 systemd-getty-generator